# I want the ball object to shrink slightly after touching it with the mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want the object to shrink after I touch it in Unity.I want the ball object to shrink slightly after touching it with the mouse. How can I do that? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Point : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;
    private Vector3 targetPosition;
    private bool isMoving;
    public GameObject clickAnimation;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {


            targetPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            targetPosition.z = transform.position.z;
            if (isMoving == false)
            {
                isMoving = true;
                Instantiate(clickAnimation, targetPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
        if (isMoving == true)
        {

            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (targetPosition == transform.position)
        {
            isMoving = false;
            Destroy(GameObject.Find("Click Animation(Clone)"));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have multiple scenarios to achieve this, dependings on what you need at the end. Let's say you want to shrink any object clicked by the mouse.

You want to raycast everytime you click, and get the gameobject that was hit. In order to do this, you can use the RaycastHit and get the gameobject using `RaycastHit.transform.gameObject`, you can find the implementation right [there](https://answers.unity.com/questions/141529/getting-gameobject-from-raycast-hit.html) and the official Unity documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html).

After you retrieved your gameobject from the raycast hit, you can shrink it using the `setScale` transform method. Think that you can use the Vector3 class operator overloading to create the new scale vector.

If you want to shrink the object during the click, you'll have to use `Time.deltaTime` to "create" the shrink animation.